# Specific heat of the classical ferromagnetic Heisenberg model

Tags: electromagnetism, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter

I have simulated the classical ferromagnetic Heisenberg model on a cubic lattice using Monte Carlo and I get a finite specific heat near zero temperature. My understanding is that from the magnon theory, 
we should get a specific heat that behaves like ~ $T^{3/2}$. I have looked everywhere to find an answer to this question, but I have found none. I have read somewhere about the number of ground states not being necessarily the same for a finite system as for an infinite one, but I can't quite see 
the connection. Any help with this question will be much appreciated. The included figure is a sample of the results that I have obtained.

[image: Specific heat of the classical ferromagnetic Heisenberg model on a cubic lattice using Monte Carlo]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is essentially a result of the [equipartition theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipartition_theorem) where each degree of freedom contributes $k_B T/2$ to the energy. Given that the specific heat in this context is just ${\partial E}/{\partial T}$ then each degree of freedom contributes $k_B/2$ to the specific heat. For the classical model of lattice vibrations in solids this leads to the [Dulong-Petit Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dulong%E2%80%93Petit_law); i.e. a constant specific heat.

For the classical Heisenberg model of interest the analogous harmonic modes are the spin waves about the ferromagnetically ordered state. Since there are as many spin wave modes as sites, and each contributes two degrees of freedom (roughly: the two directions transverse to the ordered moment) you would expect an energy per site from these modes of $E = 2 (k_B T/2) = k_BT$ and thus a contribution to the specific heat of $C \sim k_B$. In more natural units this would be $C \sim 1$, as you find in your simulations. This should only occur at low temperature (well below the ordering transition) where this spin-waves are well defined.

In regard to the $C \sim T^{3/2}$ law for magnons; this is a result of quantum mechanics, in the same way the low temperature [Debye specific heat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debye_model), $C \sim T^3$, is for phonons. To find this result one needs both the ferromagnetic dispersion that goes as $\omega \sim k^2$ at long wave-lengths, as well as Bose statistics for the magnons.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. If I understand well, then if one did a classical molecular dynamics simulation 
of a solid and computed its specific heat, than one would get the Dulong-Petit rather than the Debye law close 
to zero temperature.

Comment: In fact I found an alternative clue in this paprer [ PRB 91, 
144425 (2015)]. They give the occupation number of a spin wave of energy \epsilon_k as n_k=k_BT/\epsilon_k. 
They say it corresponds to the high temperature limit of the Boltzmann law.  I can't see 
how does n_k=k_BT/\epsilon_k come from the Boltzmann distribution exp(-\epsilon_k/k_BT). But instead, we 
could obtain the result from the high temperature limit of the Bose-Einstein distribution. My worry is that we
are using a high-temperature approximation when we are actually computing the specific heat at low temperature!

Comment: As to the molecular dynamics; I'd say yes, if such simulations thermalized and eventually followed classical thermodynamics (I don't know if they really do). As to your statement about magnon occupation: yes, this is again equipartition. If $n_k = k_B T/\epsilon_k$ then the contribution to the energy of the mode is $n_k \epsilon_k = k_B T$. As you said this is the high temperature limit of the Bose distribution which, as it must, reduces to the Boltzmann distribution.

Comment: As to your statement about the high-temperature limit: the way I would think about it would be that you are using the Boltzmann distribution from the outset, not taking the high temperature limit of an underlying Bose distribution. Conceptually then there is no issue in studying such a model at low temperatures.